# How to hide the window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

In my project,I added a extra NSWindowController named`NewWindow`.Now I want add an button to hiden/view the wimdow.My code as following.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NewWindow.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *view;
- (IBAction)showNewWindow:(id)sender;
@end
@implementation AppDelegate
{
 NewWindow *newWindow;
 BOOL isNewWindowLoad;
}
-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {
      newWindow = [[NewWindow alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}
- (IBAction)showNewWindow:(id)sender
{
   if(!isNewWindowLoad)
   {
     [newWindow loadWindow];
     isNewWindowsLoad = YES;
   }
   else
   {
     [[newWindow window] close];
     isNewWindowLoad = NO;
   }
}
@end
```

the window can load,but it can't be hidden.
Anyone can tell me how to do it?Through clicking the button to control the window load/hidden.

Comment: Where is `newWindow` allocated and initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Call `orderOut` to hide the window. It's still there, you can call `orderFront` or `makeKeyAndOrderFront` to show it again.