# Xcode Swift MacOs - Hide/Show windows without a StoryBoard and without ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appdelegate

**I'm making an App on my Apple macOS computer by using Swift 3**

Close a window is eazy [in this way] from my main window called `w` by clicking button and calling the function `closeotherw()`

```
@IBOutlet var w: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet var otherw: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var otherw: NSPanel!
    @IBAction func closeotherw(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        otherw.close()
    }
```

**But how to reopen-it [otherwin]?**

I also tried it in all ways, also like `w.isHidden = true` but with no results.

I don't have a `StoryBoard` and I also don't have a `ViewController`.

**I'm doing all from `AppDelegate`.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837972/how-to-hide-the-window)

Comment: @Willeke No. If i make ```otherw.orderOut()``` the error is ```Missing argument for parameter #1 in call```

Comment: @Willeke tnks it work ```otherw.orderOut(self)```it the way

Answer (score 1):

Method is:
**`otherw.orderFront(self)`**

Also there is:

> makeKeyAndOrderFront to show it again.

You can use `otherw.orderOut(self)` instead `otherw.close()`

tnks to @Willeke

reference:
[How to hide the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837972/how-to-hide-the-window)

Good learning!